# Is this a typo ? "The order of $1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is infinite."

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Example 1.4.4 (Examples of orders)
> The order of $−1$ in $(\Bbb Q,\times)$ is $2$, while the order of $1$ in $\Bbb Z$ is infinite.

I got this from Evan Chen's "napkin". Right after this definition:

> Definition 1.4.3. The order of an element $g \in G$ is the smallest positive integer $n$ such that $g^n=1_G$, or $\infty$ if no such $n$ exists. We denote this by ord $g$.

Maybe this is a dumb questions but isn't the order ......
.....

...drumroll please......

$1$ ?

Comment: They are considering $\mathbb Z$ as an *additive* group.  Note that $\mathbb Z$ is not a group under multiplication, as most elements lack inverses.

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}$, the default operator is the addition operator. So, the identity is $0_{\mathbb{Z}}$, and there does not exist $n>0$ such that $1n = 0$.

Comment: This makes sense, thank you!